# search bar and button css

Tags: css, search

Having trouble getting my search bar and search  button lined up correctly. Any help would be great.

I'll post more code if you need it. Here's the site live.

http://foyermakeover.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

I want it to line up with the menu. Thanks.

Here's the html. I'm using two css. One is from Business Catalyst called Module something. I believe this css file controls the search box. I just don't know which rule to modify.

```
<!-- Higher Menu Start -->
<!-- DC Mega Menu Start -->
<div class="fm_menu_top">
        <ul id="dc_mega-menu-white" class="dc_mm-white">
            <li><a href="/shop.html">SHOP </a></li>
            <li><a href="/gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DOOR BUILDER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STAIR BUILDER</a></li>     
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>

        </ul>


<!-- Higher Menu End -->
<!-- Search Begin -->

<form name="catsearchform60238" method="post" action="/Default.aspx?SiteSearchID=2433&PageID=/search.html"><div class="cat_textbox">
  <input name="CAT_Search" type="text" class="CAT_Searchy" id="CAT_Searchy" placeholder="Type text here..." value="" />
  <input class="fm_letsearch" type="image" src="/images/search.png" value="Search" /></div></form>
</div>

<!-- Search End -->
```

Comment: I'll post more code if you need it. **Yes, we do** ...and a JSfiddle would help too. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: posted some html just solely on the menu and search bar.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack to do this would be by setting a negative top.
Add to your css ore style definition:

```
 .CAT_Searchy{
     position:relative;
     top:-18px
 }
```

Which would align like this:

[image]

Or just use the good ole table layout.

Comment: Although it is a lot of reading and trying, you should consider @Radixs suggestion. This looks still crappy and it wouldn't look much better if you blow up height and fontsize of your input. Maybe find another place for your inputbox and rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

U can include boostrap, and then use the inline list to line up ur links and the search 
Refer : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists